# WPF LoadComponent problem with absolute uri

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have declared a part of my UI in an external XAML file. I am trying to load it using `Application.LoadComponent(uri)` but I get an exception telling me that I cannot use absolute uris. The XAML file I want to load is located in an arbitrary disk location.

I have successfully used `LoadComponent` during testing to load XAML files included in my project. Prior to this I have tried using `XamlReader` but this one didn't set some of the attached properties I was using in the XAML.

Is there any way to achieve this or am I totally on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem by using `XamlReader`. The reason why this did not work before is because the namespace for my attached property was declared without `assembly=` part. After adding that, `XamlReader` happily loaded my XAML as expected.

Comment: how can you use XamlReader to load a absolute URI?