# How to load a window from absolute uri?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

my job is to open a WPF Window, all I have is a absolute URI:

```
string path = "pack://application:,,,/ExternalAssembly;component/Window1.xaml";
```

this window is in a different assembly, of cause.

So I try to:

```
Window window = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute)) as Window;
```

Exception raised said: can not use absolute uri.
then I try to use XamlReader.Load, but all load functions don't accept uri(stream only).

So, how can I load such a window and ShowDialog() it out?

**EDIT**

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620656/how-does-use-xamlreader-to-load-from-a-xaml-file-from-within-the-assembly) already, I didn't try it because my thinking is: if I have a absolute URI, why I need to reflect that? waiting for better answer, thanks.

**EDIT 2**

Sorry guys, I don't need to exactly call PrintWindow class, Window class is enough because all I need to do is call window.ShowDialog() method.

Comment: If your `Window.xaml` is not compiled with `Embedded Resource`, then your xaml will simply be compiled into binaries. There is no source code anymore, so how would you be able to load it?

Comment: Have you looked into that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887578/wpf-loadcomponent-problem-with-absolute-uri?rq=1 I dont think its a duplicate, however it could solve your problem. Maybe you need the assembly= ?

Comment: @Mafii thank you for the information he use XamlReader but I dont found XamlReader can read from an absolute uri.

Comment: @Jai all assemblies are in one same solution, so mine. but the problem is my assembly is referenced by UI layer(in my code case, ExternalAssembly), so i cannot call anything out from that assembly.

Comment: If all assemblies are in the same solution, is the window internal? Why do you really want to load it with its path? There is certanly another way - is there a reason you must use the path?

Comment: @Mafii this window will show up and collect static data then send to printer. All I need to do is setup data, then call this window out once. I'm a  tiny part of this project, I have no idea how and why they design this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

> all assemblies are in one same solution, so mine. but the problem is
>   my assembly is referenced by UI layer(in my code case,
>   ExternalAssembly), so i cannot call anything out from that assembly

I can say, that passing URI is *very* indirect way to solve this task.
While you could parse pack URI and get assembly and type info from it, the easiest way is to pass window from calling assembly or declare some factory/provider inside your assembly, if you want to decide yourself, when to create window:

```
public interface IWindowFactory
{
    Window CreatePrintWindow();
}

public void YourMethod(IWindowFactory windowFactory)
{
    // ...
    var window = windowFactory.CreatePrintWindow();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: hi @Dennies quite depressed to hear what you said. I wondering why I can use absolute uri any where to load pages(use Frame) but can not locate and read a Window's xaml?

Comment: hi @Dennies I edit my topic: "I don't need to exactly call PrintWindow class, Window class is enough because all I need to do is call window.ShowDialog() method.". it is now possible?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it as simple as this?

```
Window window = new ExternalAssembly.Window1();
window.ShowDialog();
```

### Edit

The assembly's project must be part of the solution or be in the reference list.

Comment: sorry it's not. I implement a tiny print function only, so they gave me a PrintWindow Uri to me to call it out and print data. the UI layers reference my assembly.

Comment: @OhMyDog You can not instantiate a WPF window by simply loading the XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Simply loading the XAML is not enough to create a WPF window. You also need some code behind that initializes stuff and contains the program logic (the window class).

What you actually need to do is to (either statically or dynamically) load the respective assembly and instantiate the Window class.